# Alert admin without email

Tags: email, automation, alert

I am currently writing an automation script (bash or batch), but I am stuck at one logic.

- If some function (e.g. a service fails) fails, first solution is to send an email alert to admin.
  But If email does not work, what and how could I send alert to admin ? Please provide hint for considering - With internet connectivity and without internet connectivity.

I am looking for solutions in Windows and Linux both (version do not matter to me). I am not looking for any code here. If you could just provide some hint, that would do for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may send [SMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sms) via non email based internet service or directly (e.g. via cheap USB GSM/LTE modem).

Another method is are periodical "heart beat" emails with admin side scripting detecting (two?) missing heart beats.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it is impossible for me to use SMS as it also has to be a secure environment.

Comment: So add "extra hints" to your question e.g. alert admin anytime located anywhere **OR** alert admin present somewhere on the premises